# regex - find out strings that contains one word or its substring not followed by a certain character

Tags: regex

I should match any strings that contains "checkout" or "checkout.html" not followed by "?" with regex.

For example:

```
www.xxx.com/en/cp/checkout.html?basket_gotostep=4  FALSE
www.xxx.com/en/cp/checkout.html=test  OK
www.xxx.com/en/cp/checkout=test_23   OK
www.xxx.com/en/cp/checkout?basket_gotostep=4 FALSE
```

This is what I've tried:`((checkout\.html)(?!\?))|((checkout)(?!\?))` but it doesnt work.

Comment: Try  `\bcheckout\b(?!(?:\.html)?\?)`, see https://regex101.com/r/vglqmB/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex like

```
\bcheckout\b(?!(?:\.html)?\?)
```

Or

```
\/checkout\b(?!(?:\.html)?\?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vglqmB/3)

**Details**

- `\/checkout\b` - `/checkout` followed with a word boundary check
- `(?!(?:\.html)?\?)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is an optional `.html` sequence followed with a `?` char.